# Additional jQuery popups not initialized after ajax return

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile-popup

I'm using a pageless solution for displaying a list of locations. Some of these locations include this jQuery popup for additional data to be displayed in the box. The problem however, is that on following ajax appends, the new locations added to continue the page going down don't maintain the popup functionality.

How do I initialize the new popups added to the page?

```
<div data-role="popup" id="@l.location_id"  data-corners="false" data-tolerance="50,30">
    Content
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't show how the popups are initialized, but you probably need to use event delegation to initialize dynamically-created elements, too. More code, please.

Comment: The initialization is right there. See: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/popup/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sending folks out into the internets to see code isn't consider good practice. Show *your* code *here*, in your question, please.

Comment: Please move on since you don't understand that the initialization of this jquery popup is within the question already.

Comment: Are you calling `$("#id_of_your_div").popup();` after adding the HTML dynamically? Just using data attributes won't work with dynamically added elements.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more cleaner somehow, but thanks! Should have submitted this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads and jQuery mobile is initialized, it'll look for any divs with the attribute `data-role="popup"` and initialize the popup. The problem is that this code runs once on page load and dynamically created divs are not registered. You can however initialize the popup widget programmatically by doing

```
$(selector).popup()
```

`selector` can be the `id` of the newly added div.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the CSS for the close button on the new popups has to be reintroduced to the page too. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not too sure what you mean. Are you saying the look of the close button is not the same as on the other popups? If so, you'll just need to ensure that the same css classes are specified in the newly added div. Take a look here [http://jsfiddle.net/3cbw2765/](http://jsfiddle.net/3cbw2765/)